# Scala macro: restrict variable names

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I have a method `def getCountryAtPosition(lat: Double, lon: Double) = ???` which is obviously error-prone due to possibility of accidental switching arguments. I don't want to change API to something more typeful though.

Instead of that I want to make impossible to pass a variable to the method if it has suspicious name:

```
val latitude = 10.00D
val longitude = 20.00D
getCountryAtPosition(longitude, latitude)
```

I'd like to reject this code because a variable passed to `lat` has `lon` suffix and vice versa. Is it possible to achieve it via, say, scala macro?

Comment: *prefix* probably. But interesting question. I guess you'd also need a way to force callers to use the macro and not the function directly.

Comment: Good point. Yeah, separate compilation would probably break my idea.

Comment: It has to be said, though: Not wanting to refactor the API to use more typesafe types eliminates the probably best (and least complex/hacky) option. How would restricting variable naming even work when there are no variables involved (`getCountryAtPosition(10, 20)`)?

Comment: Yes, I understand downsides.

Comment: And even with fixing this function, doesn't this just push the problem to somewhere else? Eventually, someone still has to assign values to these two inputs, and can still muck it up. Ideally you get the numbers from some "known-good" library for geo-parsing or such and can pass through whatever types they already have without an extra (error-prone) translation step.

Comment: You can also use named arguments

Comment: Why not a more "typeful" API ? Does it not look like a variation of `Anti-Corruption Layer pattern` ?

Comment: Anti-Corruption layer pattern doesn't address the particular issue raised, since argument order can really only be addressed by making latitude syntactically different from longitude.